# In a .bat file on Win 10, quotes around "folder name with spaces" does NOT work

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

In a .bat file to run on Win 10 Pro 64-bit, the append phrase

```
[source] >> "c:\Users\My UserName with space\OneDrive\Desktop\document.txt"
```

is **NOT working because of a space in a folder name even though I surround the whole thing with "" quote marks.**

I've looked up a lot of posts about this, and there is no explanation for this.

To get where I need to go, I am putting successive cd lines in the .bat file, like

```
cd c:\Users
cd "My UserName with space"
cd OneDrive\Desktop
[source] >> document.txt
```

That seems to be working.

But

```
[source] >> "c:\Users\My UserName with space\OneDrive\Desktop\document.txt"
```

does NOT work.  When I run that line, the PC puts the source text into c:\Users\My

??

Thanks.

Comment: It should work. Only thing I can think of is some weird backwards compatibility thing attached to the .bat extension. If you rename your file to .cmd does it work then?

Comment: Probably some Unicode character in the path

Comment: LPChip - I'll try that, but the .bat file started as a .txt file and then I changed .txt to .bat.  Yes, I originally copied that .bat file from an earlier PC and then edited it to have the correct new folder and file names, but why would that be an issue or explain why it works with my successive cd lines?

Comment: .bat is executed slightly different than .cmd and is meant to work like old MSDos where no long paths existed. Although the .bat has some changes to accomodate the modern featureset, there is a difference between .bat and .cmd and I learned that if a .bat script doesn't work, a .cmd may work for some obscure reasons. I therefor never use .bat anymore on modern systems, always .cmd

Comment: See also: https://www.educba.com/cmd-vs-bat/

Comment: Is there an amperstand (&) in the path? Are you using onedrive "business"?

Comment: It might be better to post online your exact `.bat` file.

Comment: Also the `cd` is one of the few  commands that don't require quotes. See `cd /?`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with quotes while i was creating a .bat file to automatically log in to my ser in MySQL.

***cmd /K “C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe” -uroot -ppasword!***

wasn't working.I tried putting double quotes like this:

***cmd /K “"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe”" -uroot -pAbubakr12!***

and it worked! I don't know if it will help you but still.